# VBA Word copy Table

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

Sorry in advance for my bad English and may be simple question.
I want to copy Table object into Dictionary for place it later in another Word document. All works are in Excel VBA.
I try it for copy table:

```
Dim dict As Dictionary
Dim table1 As Word.table
Set table1 = Word.Application.ActiveDocument.Tables.Item(tableNum)                                            
dict.Add "SampleText","MyText"
dict.Add "tab1", table1
```

After it I close this document and open another. In it, I try to insert data from Dictionary to Bookmarks:

```
dim prilDoc As Word.Document
...
prilDoc.Bookmarks.Item("SampleText").Range.Text=dict.Item("SampleText")
```

this (insert text) work fine, but I don't know, how to place Table object on Bookmark place, because I don't know VBA Word Object Model. I tryed some approaches, but can't find solution. I think there are two problems:

1. When I put Table object into Dictionary, I in fact, copyed only reference to Table object in first Word document. And when I close this document and I try to get it from Dictionary object is deleted and I can't work with it. In Java I can deep cloning object, but I don't know how to do it in VBA. May be here must be use fully another approach.
2. I don't know, how correctly must I insert Table object in new Word document.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: All document pieces, including `Table`, are linked to the source document and cannot be deep-copied.

Comment: Thank you! And then how can I copy one Table to another with Dictionary? May be I can copy table to clipboard and save it content to Dictionary? If so, help me please how to do it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can copy it to the clipboard, but that also only copies by reference.  I don't think this is possible to do, unless you paste each one immediately.  (You can try experimenting with the clipboard)

Comment: You'll probably need to just copy each cell from the table into the Dictionary object.  Or, better yet, just avoid the Dictionary altogether and put the text from the table cells into the bookmarks.

Comment: I can't fully understand the question, but if you want to insert the same table in many documents, you can use Autotext or AutoCorretch Can you clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try copying with the first document open? Don't close it before the contents are copied over.